# How to access Rapidminer repository from the R console?

Tags: r, rapidminer

Basic problem: I am not happy with the Rapidminer plots (for example, there seems to be a lack of line plots). My proposed solution is using the R extension for plotting.

But how do I access Rapidminer repository data from the Rapidminer R console?

Bonus if you can provide a link to documentation for the plugin (Who decided to call this thing R? ;-)  )

Comment: https://rapidminer.com/rapidminer-and-r/

Comment: It's called R because that's the first letter of the names of the two guys who initially wrote it.  Send my bonus to my bank account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R variable view lets you load RapidMiner repository data into R as data frames. Proceed as normal with R commands in the R console view and obtain plots in the R plot view.

Tip: Type the command x11() into the R console to get a new graphics window. This can be moved outside the RapidMiner GUI.